# Как используя material table сделать строку, которая выезжает под строкой на которую нажали?

Tags: angular2

Собственно, вопрос.

Находил вот [такой](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-expandable-table-rows?file=app%2Ftable%2Ftable.component.html) пример, но почему-то в последней версии Angular он не работает...

1. Таблица изначально раскрытая
2. При сокрытии данных на одной строке, скрываются все и больше не открываются.

Единственное изменение, которое я сделал - это убрал `when`, так у меня всегда должна быть сформирована скрытая строка.

Вот моя разметка:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" multiTemplateDataRows>
<!-- описание других колонок -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="expandedDetail">
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      {{element.description}}
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" matRipple class="element-row"
    [class.expanded]="expandedElement == row">
  </tr>

  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['expandedDetail'];"
    [@detailExpand]="row.element == expandedElement ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'" style="overflow: hidden; ">
  </tr>
</table>
```

Вот мой компонент:

```
        @Component({
          selector: 'app-list',
          templateUrl: './assembly-list.component.html',
          styleUrls: ['./assembly-list.component.css'],
          providers: [AssemblyService, VersionService],
          animations: [
            trigger('detailExpand', [
              state('collapsed', style({ height: '0px', minHeight: '0', visibility: 'hidden' })),
              state('expanded', style({ height: '*', visibility: 'visible' })),
              transition('expanded <=> collapsed', animate('225ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1)')),
            ])]
        })
        export class ListComponent implements OnInit {
          items: Item[];
          dataSource;
          expandedElement: any;
displayedColumns: string[] = ['name', 'owner', 'type', 'actions'];
          displayedColumns: string[] = ['name', 'owner', 'type', 'actions'];

      ngOnInit(): void {
          this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Item>(this.items);

        );
      }
```

Comment: можно подробнее пожалуйста?

Comment: @overthesanity дополнил.

Comment: создайте пример на stackblitz

Comment: у вас код и шаблон полностью не совпадают, в компоненте `displayedColumns` 2 продублированных массива, в шаблоне у вас `matColumnDef="expandedDetail"`, где остальные? я даже локально не могу у себя сделать этот пример